# Trying to make a list of chat_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I'm trying to make a list of `chat_id` for my Telegram bot that will allow my bot to send one message to all of the `chat_id` in the list. Here is what I tried,

```
    listofids = ['191929390', '102938483']
    bot.sendMessage(listofids, str("worked"))
```

But I'm getting this error

```
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: chat not found', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: chat not found'})
```

So what is wrong here and how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chat_id` parameter of `semdMessage` method should be `int`, not `list` or other iterable.

If you wish to send same text message to multiple recipients, do it in a loop:

```py
listofids = [191929390, 102938483]  # int here

for recipient_id in listofids:
    bot.sendMessage(recipient_id, "worked")  # no str() needed
```